# JSON is not properly turning an object into a string

Tags: javascript, json, tostring

I am making a game and am working on the accounts. When i have JSON stringify the object and save it to a file, it sometimes (occasionally and at random) writes:

```json
{"example@domain.cm":{"email":"example@domain.cm","password":"myPassword","token":"c26a2a66-77f8-43d7-aa92-14da81979386"} >}< "example@domain.com":{"email":"example@domain.com","password":"myPassword","token":"209758d0-9a6e-4e99-835a-21595b822796"}}
```

when i am expecting:

```json
{"example@domain.cm":{"email":"example@domain.cm","password":"myPassword","token":"c26a2a66-77f8-43d7-aa92-14da81979386"} >,< "example@domain.com":{"email":"example@domain.com","password":"myPassword","token":"209758d0-9a6e-4e99-835a-21595b822796"}}
```

My Code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { v4: newUuid } = require('uuid');

function save() {
    fs.writeFile('save_info/users.json', JSON.stringify(User.USERS), err => {});
}

class User {

    static USERS = {};

    constructor(email, password, token = newUuid()) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.token = token;
        User.USERS[email] = this;
        save();
    }
}
```

What is going on?

**EDIT**
I am using nodemon. Whenever i save a file (except users.json), it automatically stops and starts it. I am also using express because this script is for the server part. (This is a private project, not looking to make it perfect, just learn)

Comment: Can you supply the code you used to do this, without that it's difficult to give an accurate answer

Comment: This doesn't look like a JSON.stingify problem but a file access/write issue.

Comment: There are invalid `>` and `<` in your expected version

Comment: @charlietfl Those are there to help point out the character that is having an issue.

Comment: What is `User.USERS`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could this be the problem: _"It is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback."_

Comment: Try to save using `writeFileSync` instead and see if it is reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @jabaa
they have pointed out a warning that using `fs.writeFile()` multiple times without waiting for the callback is unsafe. Here is the solution:

```js
var CAN_SAVE = true;
var PENDING_SAVE = false;
function save() {
    if (!CAN_SAVE) {
        PENDING_SAVE = true;
        return;
    }
    PENDING_SAVE = false;
    CAN_SAVE = false;
    fs.writeFile('save_info/users.json', JSON.stringify(User.USERS), err => {
        CAN_SAVE = true;
        if (PENDING_SAVE) save();
    });
}
```

Another solution is to use `fs.writeFileSync()`, which might actually be better in my case... (Thank you, @Steven Spungin)

Comment: or just use a synchronous write instead.

Comment: @StevenSpungin Yea i guess that would work too XD

Comment: Don't use `writeFileSync` in a server request handler.